# Issues while untaring in Linux- tarball created from Solaris

Tags: linux, unix, solaris, tar, gnu

I am getting an error- `Unknown file type 'A', extracted as normal file` 
while un-tarring a set of files which has acl permissions set.

I had created the tar file in solaris as       `tar -cpfv Tarfilename.tar  directory`
if I un-tar as `tar xvpf Tarfilename.tar`, it works great in solaris.

I had copied the tar file to Linux and tried to extract using tar xvpf, it dosen't throws the warning Unknown file type 'A', extracted as normal file and created files without ACL permissions.

`tar --version  : tar (GNU tar) 1.15.1`

Comment: Can't you just use `gtar` on Solaris? (see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66415/solaris-default-install-user-tools/66416#66416). Personally I've made it a habit always to use `gtar` on Solaris, rather than `tar`.

Answer (score 2):

## Tar Wars

The Solaris tar format handles extended headers differently to  GNU tar leading to a number of incompatibilities.

`star` (Schily Tar) provides the best Linux support for the [Solaris 7/8/9 format](http://linux.die.net/man/1/star) due to the work of Joerg Schilling over many years.

Install `star` on your system and run:

```
> star -xp artype=suntar f=Tarfilename.tar
```

### Other things to note

There are no cygwin packages available for `star`

If you ever need to go back the other way, [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108156/how-to-create-a-gnu-tarball-that-can-be-extracted-by-solaris-tar) describes how to create a tarball on a Linux system that can read on a Solaris system.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using bsdtar?
It can be installed without conflicts with gnu tar (binary is called bsdtar).